# Need to increase door height in bungalow

Tags: doors

I am in a[image]  bungalow with the doors into the bathroom and 2 bedrooms all being different height. I'd like to increase the door height and shifting the header up seemed like a simple thing. however...this is what i found and i am not sure how to proceed... i was not expecting a double header. then again i know nothing about this. any thoughts are appreciated. not sure about load bearing

Answer (score 1):

That's not a header, just a nailer. Some carpenters / builders like to use two so that the trim is easier to nail and looks better. You're fine removing one of them. Leave at least one though to nail the trim to after your done (moved or not)

Comment: thanks for the response and apologies for the delay. i will have to move both up because the door height is currently 79 inches. i need to make the header/nailer 83 inches i am told. which is fine...but i have to do this on 2 separate walls. the second wall is load bearing. can i just put a piece of 2*4 on the jack stud and raise the header on the load bearing wall or put a brand new one in? also , would you suggest i build a temporary support wall while doing so?

Comment: the other wall is load bearing and has the same framing as the picture? If so, something is amiss, either the wall isn't load bearing or the wall opening is improperly framed.

Comment: yes. I just removed the doors and the frames and none of the jack studs are one piece. this house is old... and the last guy clearly just did not care...what do i do? remove and reframe?

Comment: if the wall is load bearing then at least you need to add a load bearing header. Typically, the minimum is (2) 2x10 for typical situations (say something like 1 level, 20 ft or less roof span, opening at 5' or less). Personally, yes I would replace the jack studs to 'do it right'. One issue that can occur with fill-in pieces is that each joint is a location that needs to be 'compressed' before the load will be fully transferred and this can cause excessive defection and related issues